# Laravel giving 502 bad gateway in nginx

Tags: php, linux, laravel, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I have reloaded my server configuration to match the one provided on Laravel. When I do `php --ini` I can see my PHP version is 7.0 so I made the alterations to use 7.0.

My server config looks like this:

```
server {
    server_name exoscape.co.uk;

    root /var/www/html/exoscape/public;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/exoscape.co.uk/fullchain.pem; # manag$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/exoscape.co.uk/privkey.pem; # man$
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = exoscape.co.uk) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name exoscape.co.uk;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I have tried to ensure that the dir is `chmod` correctly by doing:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/exoscape/
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/exoscape/
```

But I still receive 502 Bad Gateway when I visit my domain. I am using `nginx/1.15.12`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock` exists?

Comment: Yes, inside of my /run/php dir there is the .pid and .sock files named correctly @loic.lopez

Comment: Do you have run `nginx -s reload`?

Comment: Yes, and I’ve restarted the service - sudo nginx -t also gives me the all clear @loic.lopez

Comment: can you provide the log of `php-fpm` daemon?